# Private view exported to excel-- how can other users refresh the data

Tags: list-view, export

My problem is we are not allowed to create a public view that shows all the data since there are a lot of confidential items in that site. In order for me to make all data available in excel, I have to create a private view which obviously only intended for me. Other users within my team who can also create private views will be using that exported file and the problem is they cannot refresh the data through that file.

Is there a way for me to share my private view so that the other users within my team can refresh the data within the exported excel file? Or is there a way wherein only certain users within my team can access that particular view? I am using SharePoint server 2010. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can create a public view. It will create a page and add list view webpart on it. You can edit the page and webpart. In advanced setting you have option of target audience. You can list users to whom you want to share. So only shared users can see that list view webpart.

Comment: Hi Bhaskar, thank you for that information. Does that webpart need any script? As far as I know, web parts have script or codes in it.

Comment: No It's OOB property of webpart.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and contact our IT Team just in case I do not how to tweak it.